# Handling dozens of sidebars

Tags: widgets, admin, wp-admin, sidebar, user-interface

We have the job to realize a page with custom sidebars. Sidebars can be created on the fly on post an page edit screens, to add a custom sidebar on each page.

The client wants to use this to add additional information, links and elements to the page/post content.

This is not the problem. The problem starts when you want to maintain the sidebars. The widgets section in the admin screen is simply not built to handle that many sidebars. It is technically possible, but the usability is horrible.

So the question is: Is there an elegant way to either add filtering to the widgets screen, or is it possible to replicate sidebar editing and widget administration in a post meta box?

Comment: customizer?...... (it should show only the widgets which are actually used on a page)

Comment: Good suggestion. Is there a way to hotlink directly into the correct customizer page on the preview screen?

Comment: Ha, that early in editing the page .... I guess that you might be able to use the preview url for that - open a preview and customizer from it or directly the costumizer with the preview url. In both cases IMO it should be easier then switching to the widgets page. (but in general I think it is bad design, you should probably try harder to change your clients mind ;) )

Comment: Both answers (Preview URL and changing customers mind) are for me a good solution. Thank you for your input!